# can Apache Camel File watch create event ensure file integrity

Tags: apache-camel, file-watcher

do file watch component has file integrity check in built? Will this assure that the file formation is fully done. for instance, file watch's  event support to monitor the file creation at a directory and. this file could be being created/written and not yet fully completed.  does file-watch monitor that file file is fully formed before its alerts/propagate file creation event.. so that when we grab the file, its not partial but upon full formation.  if not, can be we configure to verify a.file status : is not in transient (being updated) WIP state but 100% b.possible to file  integrity with algorithms that guarantee files are transferred without being tampered with between the current directory and original file like checksum etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See '**readLock**' attribute of the file component:

```
Changed is using file length/modification timestamp to detect whether the file is currently being copied or not. Will at least use 1 sec to determine this, so this option cannot consume files as fast as the others, but can be more reliable as the JDK IO API cannot always determine whether a file is currently being used by another process. The option readLockCheckInterval can be used to set the check frequency.
```